# Adding a timer in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

> Would anyone know how you would code a timer to be displayed on screen in pygame, where the time is going up as the user is playing?

Comment: If you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: example with [analog clock](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/pygame/clock)

Answer (score 0):

This link might be helpful

http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks

You can do something like this

```
start_ticks=pygame.time.get_ticks()
while mainloop:
    seconds=(pygame.time.get_ticks()-start_ticks)/1000 
    if seconds>10:
        break
```